# Libgdx Creating a popup touchpad

Tags: java, android, libgdx

First time posting here, so I hope can make myself clear.
As the title states I am creating a touchpad that popups where the user touches the device screen. The touchpad is created up front and is moved to the X, Y coordinate of the touch event. The way it is implemented now the touchpad doesn't behave as if touched after moving it, since the finger is on the screen before the touchpad is at that location. The result is that you always have to double tap before you can use it (first tap to move it, second tap to start using it). Is there a way to solve this, by for instance firing a second "artificial" touch event at the same location? If possible please provide a code example.

This my repositioning code:

```
    if(popupMode) {
            // Adjust the touchpad position when in popup mode
            if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
                // Assume at most 2 fingers touch the screen simultaneously
                boolean left, right;
                left = false;
                right = false;
                int x0, x1, y0, y1;
                x0 = -1;
                x1 = -1;
                y0 = -1;
                y1 = -1;

                if(Gdx.input.isTouched(0)) {
                    x0 = Gdx.input.getX(0);
                    y0 = Gdx.input.getY(0);

                    if(x0 < (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2.0f))
                        left = true;
                    else
                        right = true;
                }

                if(Gdx.input.isTouched(1)) {
                    x1 = Gdx.input.getX(1);
                    y1 = Gdx.input.getY(1);

                    if(x1 < (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2.0f))
                        left = true;
                    else
                        right = true;
                }

                if(left) {
                    if(!repositionedMove) {
                        if(     (x0 > -1) && 
                                (x0 > (touchpadMove.getWidth() / 2)) && 
                                (x0 < ((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) - (touchpadMove.getWidth() / 2))) &&
                                (y0 > (touchpadMove.getHeight() / 2)) && 
                                (y0 < (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - (touchpadMove.getHeight() / 2)))) {
                            touchpadMove.setX(x0 - (touchpadMove.getWidth() / 2));
                            touchpadMove.setY((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - y0) - (touchpadMove.getHeight() / 2));
                            touchpadMove.layout();
                            repositionedMove = true;
                        }
                        if(     (x1 > -1) && 
                                (x1 > (touchpadMove.getWidth() / 2)) && 
                                (x1 < ((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) - (touchpadMove.getWidth() / 2))) &&
                                (y1 > (touchpadMove.getHeight() / 2)) && 
                                (y1 < (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - (touchpadMove.getHeight() / 2)))) {
                            touchpadMove.setX(x1 - (touchpadMove.getWidth() / 2));
                            touchpadMove.setY((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - y1) - (touchpadMove.getHeight() / 2));
                            touchpadMove.layout();
                            repositionedMove = true;
                        }
                    }                       
                }
                else
                    repositionedMove = false;

                if(right) {
                    if(!repositionedRotate) {
                        if(     (x0 > -1) && 
                                (x0 > ((touchpadRotate.getWidth() / 2) + (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2))) && 
                                (x0 < (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - (touchpadRotate.getWidth() / 2))) &&
                                (y0 > (touchpadRotate.getHeight() / 2)) && 
                                (y0 < (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - (touchpadRotate.getHeight() / 2)))) {
                            touchpadRotate.setX(x0 - (touchpadRotate.getWidth() / 2));
                            touchpadRotate.setY((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - y0) - (touchpadRotate.getHeight() / 2));
                            touchpadRotate.layout();
                            repositionedRotate = true;
                        }
                        if(     (x1 > -1) && 
                                (x1 > ((touchpadRotate.getWidth() / 2) + (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2))) && 
                                (x1 < (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - (touchpadRotate.getWidth() / 2))) &&
                                (y1 > (touchpadRotate.getHeight() / 2)) && 
                                (y1 < (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - (touchpadRotate.getHeight() / 2)))) {
                            touchpadRotate.setX(x1 - (touchpadRotate.getWidth() / 2));
                            touchpadRotate.setY((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - y1) - (touchpadRotate.getHeight() / 2));
                            touchpadRotate.layout();
                            repositionedRotate = true;
                        }                           
                    }
                }
                else
                    repositionedRotate = false;
            }
            else {
                repositionedMove = false;
                repositionedRotate = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't  you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Inserted the part where I reposition the touchpads. Sorry for the added white space, but I copied from eclipse.

Comment: I don't get neither what you want to achieve, nor your code. Try to explain it a bit better and maybe refactor the code a bit... 1 huge block of weird if/else stuff with hundreds of calculations aren't maintainable...

Comment: Well as stated in the text I want to **Touchpad** to popup at the position of my finger whenever I touch the screen. But the problem is that it doesn't count as if **touched**, since my finger is already on the screen before I move the Touchpad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem a while ago. To solve it, I used the artificial touch event approach.

In short, you have to:

- detect if the screen was just touched
- convert the touch point into local coordinates
- pop up the touchpad at those coordinates
- fire an artificial faked touch down event to get the touchpad to do something

Similarly, when you detect that the screen is no longer being touched then you hide the touchpad.

```
package com.badlydrawngames.wf.controllers;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent.Type;

public class FloatingThumbpadController extends FixedThumbpadController {

    private Vector2 screenPos;
    private Vector2 localPos;
    private InputEvent fakeTouchDownEvent;

    public FloatingThumbpadController() {
        screenPos = new Vector2();
        localPos = new Vector2();
        fakeTouchDownEvent = new InputEvent();
        fakeTouchDownEvent.setType(Type.touchDown);
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2 getDirection() {
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            // Get the touch point in screen coordinates.
            screenPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());

            // Convert the touch point into local coordinates, place the touchpad and show it.
            localPos.set(screenPos);
            localPos = touchpad.getParent().screenToLocalCoordinates(localPos);
            touchpad.setPosition(localPos.x - touchpad.getWidth() / 2, localPos.y - touchpad.getHeight() / 2);
            touchpad.setVisible(true);

            // Fire a touch down event to get the touchpad working. 
            Vector2 stagePos = touchpad.getStage().screenToStageCoordinates(screenPos);
            fakeTouchDownEvent.setStageX(stagePos.x);
            fakeTouchDownEvent.setStageY(stagePos.y);
            touchpad.fire(fakeTouchDownEvent);
        }
        else if (!Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            // The touch was just released, so hide the touchpad.
            touchpad.setVisible(false);
        }

        return super.getDirection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rod, this definitely puts me in the right direction! I'm just curious what you mean with local coordinates in this scenario? I know that touch events use a coordinate system with the origin in the top left corner instead of the bottom left corner, is that what you fix in your screenToLocalCoordinates and screenToStageCoordinates methods? Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sort of. The code I posted uses libgdx's scene2d for the GUI, so the local coordinates are coordinates relative to whatever the touchpad's parent is in the scene graph.